# Get cells indexes of raster file inside a rasterized border line in python

Tags: python, indexing, polygon, raster

I have a closed line made of raster cells of which I know the indexes (col and raw of each cell stored in a list). List is like -

[image]

I would like to get the indexes of the cells within this closed line and store them in a separate list. I want to do this in python. Here is an image to be more clear: Raster boundary line

[image]

Comment: Are you certain, that you want to list ALL inner points (i.e. cells within the boundary)? From the indices given in your first picture it seems as if that could be a rather large set, perhaps too large to be handled efficiently. If all you need (later) is a way to test membership, it would probably be better to test that on a one by one basis.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to implement your own (naive) algorithm, which was my first idea. One the other hand, why reinvent the wheel:

One can easily see that the problem can be interpreted as a black and white (raster/pixel) image. Then the outer and inner area form the background (black) while the border is a closed (white) loop. (Obviously the colors could also switched, but I will use white on black for now.) As it happens there are some fairly sophisticated image processing libraries for python, namely [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/), [ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/ndimage.html) and [mahotas](http://mahotas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I'm no expert but I think `skimage.draw.polygon`, `skimage.draw.polygon_perimiter` are the easiest way to solve your problem.

My experimentation yielded the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from skimage.draw import polygon, polygon_perimeter
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

# some test data 
#   I used the format that your input data is in
#   These are 4+99*4 points describing the border of a 99*99 square 
border_points = (
    [[100,100]] + 
    [[100,100+i] for i in range(1,100)] +
    [[100,200]] + 
    [[100+i,200] for i in range(1,100)] + 
    [[200,200]] + 
    [[200,200-i] for i in range(1,100)] +
    [[200,100]] + 
    [[200-i,100] for i in range(1,100)]
    )

# convert to numpy arrays which hold the x/y coords for all points 
#   repeat first point at the end to close polygon.
border_points_x = np.array( [p[0] for p in border_points] + [border_points[0][0]] )
border_points_y = np.array( [p[1] for p in border_points] + [border_points[0][1]] )

# empty (=black) 300x300 black-and-white image
image = np.zeros((300, 300))

# polygon() calculates the indices of a filled polygon
#   one would expect this to be inner+border but apparently it is inner+border/2
#   probably some kind of "include only the left/top half"
filled_rr, filled_cc = polygon(border_points_y, border_points_x)
 # set the image to white at these points
image[filled_rr, filled_cc] = 1

# polygon_perimeter() calculates the indices of a polygon perimiter (i.e. border)
border_rr, border_cc = polygon_perimeter(border_points_y, border_points_x)
# exclude border, by setting it to black
image[border_rr, border_cc] = 0

# label() detects connected patches of the same color and enumerates them
#   the resulting image has each of those regions filled with its index
label_img, num_regions = label(image, background=0, return_num=True)

# regionprops() takes a labeled image and computes some measures for each region 
regions = regionprops(label_img)
inner_region = regions[0]

print("area", inner_region.area)
# expecting 9801 = 99*99 for inner

# this is what you want, the coords of all inner points
inner_region.coords 

# print it
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```